# Sorting a hash by the results of a method, ordering nil results to the bottom

Tags: ruby, sorting, integer, null

```
def valueize(val)
  # randomly returns nil or random integer ([-100 to +100] + val)
  ((rand(100) % 3) == 0) ? nil : (rand(200)-100+val)
end

hash = {
  x: 11,
  y: 22,
  z: 33
 }

sort_by_abs = hash.sort_by{ |k, v|  (valueize(v)).abs }
sort_by_min = hash.sort_by{ |k, v|  (valueize(v))     }
sort_by_max = hash.sort_by{ |k, v| -(valueize(v))     }
```

What is the most rubyish way of ensuring nil results are always sorted to the bottom, for each of the three sorts?

Conditions:

- Range of potential hash values is **unknown** (hash values will always be integers)
- valueize method **cannot** be modified
- sort blocks **can** be modified

Comment: you probably mean `hash.sort_by { |k, v| ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple approach (using ick's `maybe` just to keep it compact, do an assignment + conditional if you feel more confortable with it):

```
inf = Float::INFINITY
sort_by_abs = hash.sort_by { |k, v| valueize(v).maybe.abs || inf }
sort_by_min = hash.sort_by { |k, v| valueize(v) || inf }
sort_by_max = hash.sort_by { |k, v| valueize(v).maybe.send(:-@) || inf }
```

Comment: Thank you, that is perfect. Although in my case I am using +inf.

Comment: I also learned about (:-@), where can I find out more about the convention for sending methods like -?

Comment: by "bottom" you mean the end of the array, ok, updating. unary operators: http://www.rubyinside.com/rubys-unary-operators-and-how-to-redefine-their-functionality-5610.html